# wygwam adding paragraph tags when embedding video

Tags: wygwam

I'm trying to embed a video into an entry. My code looks like this

```
<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.0/flowplayer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="embed_media">
    <div class="flowplayer">
        <video preload="none">
            <source src="/downloads/video/SSS_FallProtection2011.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

After I submit the entry and edit it again... a number of paragraph tags are getting added and the above code starts looking like this:

```
<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.0/flowplayer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="embed_media">
    <div class="flowplayer">
        <video preload="none">
            <source src="/downloads/video/SSS_FallProtection2011.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source></video>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <source src="/downloads/video/SSS_FallProtection2011.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p>
        <source src="/downloads/video/SSS_FallProtection2011.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source></p>
    <source src="/downloads/video/SSS_FallProtection2011.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

I'm running EE 2.5.5 with WYGWAM 2.7.1.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

When you submit your embed code did you use the embed pop-up?

see attached screenshot of the filmstrip icon. If you click that you paste your embed code there and all should be good.

[image]